# Navbar Not Expanding in bootstrap material

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I am creating a web app in which i am using navbar from bootstrap material

[From Here](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html)

and this is the code for the which is troubling me

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
           <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="#" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Dropdown
             <b class="caret"></b>
             </a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
```

there is a section there where dropdown is written with an down arrow in the web site when i clicked on dropdown options are opening like how it is supposed to open but when i copy the code and paste the same in my program, the code stops working

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
<b class="caret"></b>
```

TO

```
<span class="caret"></span>
```

If this does not work for further reference try this (it is the whole code) then replace default values with the ones you would like

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="max-width: 300px;">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Disabled</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" data-target="#" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The down arrow needs to be surrounded in a span element not a b element. If my answer helped you please accept it :)

Happy coding